# AgGrid React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ag-grid

Any good examples out there of using [AgGrid](https://www.ag-grid.com/) with React [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/). Especially around creating custom themes. The examples on the AgGrid site are around css / scss not styled components the preferred approach with React Material UI.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be exactly what you are looking for. Try searching for
[component types and custom renderers](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/component-types/)  as it contributes to customizing your ag-grid look